# Client-side unobtrusive validation for EditorTemplate when sending IEnumerable<T>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation, fluentvalidation, mvc-editor-templates

There is a possibility that I just wasn't able to find the solution, or lack thereof, through my searches. Maybe I didn't word it properly, but my problem is trying to get client-side unobtrusive validation to fire on an `EditorTemplate` when I pass an `IEnumerable<T>` to it. My setup:

**ParentModel.cs**

```
[Validator(typeof(ParentModelValidator))]
public class ParentModel
{
     ...
     public IEnumerable<ChildModel> ChildModels { get; set; }
}

public class ParentModelValidator : AbstractValidator<ParentModel>
{
    public ParentModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.ChildModels).SetCollectionValidator(new ChildModelValidator());
    }
}
```

**ChildModel.cs**

```
[Validator(typeof(ChildModelValidator))]
public class ChildModel
{
     public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
     public string foo { get; set; }
}

public class ChildModelValidator : AbstractValidator<ChildModel>
{
    public ChildModelValidator ()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.foo)
            .NotEmpty().When(x => x.IsRequired);
    }
}
```

**ParentShell.cshtml**

```
@model ParentModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Application", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.Partial("_Parent", Model)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ChildModels)
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

The `_Parent` partial just contains a handful of common, reusable `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.bar)` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.bar)` fields.

**ChildModel.cshtml** `EditorTemplate`

```
@model ChildModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.foo)
@if (Model.IsRequired)
{
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.foo)
}
```

The client-side validation fires for all fields in the `_Parent` partial, but I get nothing when `IsRequired` is true and should have a `ValidationMessageFor`. Is this a known constraint of the client-side unobtrusive validation with `EditorTemplate` that receives an `IEnumerable<T>`? Is it due to the indexer that gets inserted during rendering (`ChildModels[0].foo` and `ChildModels_0__.foo`)?

Comment: Is it that your rules aren't being run or that you are only outputting html of the validation message when IsRequired=true? If IsRequired is not set to true on the child models on the server on the GET, then according to @if (Model.IsRequired)
{
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.foo)
} no validation message will be written to the GET response stream. So on the client when your validation kicks in and validates IsRequired then regardless of result there is no ValidationMessage html to be made visible.

Comment: @rism - Some of the child models have `IsRequired` set to true, others do not. Even if I remove the `@if` and output a `ValidationMessageFor` for every child model, I still get nothing on the client. The message spans are rendered `<span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="ChildModels[0].foo" class="field-validation-valid"></span>` where the `<input>` has an `id=ChildModels_0__foo`.

Comment: @ethorn10, The `id` and `name` attributes are exactly as they should be (model binding would not work if they weren't) so that not the problem. I'm not familiar with the fluent validation your using, but if instead, you used a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) [RequiredIfTrue("IsRequired")]` attribute, it will work.

Comment: @ethorn10, I'm guessing your using [this fluent validation](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc). From the documentation, _Note that FluentValidation will also work with ASP.NET MVC's client-side validation, but not all rules are supported. For example, any rules defined using **a condition (with When/Unless)**, custom validators, or calls to Must will not run on the client side_

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke. I hadn't seen that bit in the docs. Also, I knew the `id` and `name` were written that way for model binding, but I think that might be why our various unobtrusive validation options aren't working. Because I tried the foolproof option you linked to, and it still doesn't fire on the client.

Comment: Did you include a hidden input for the `IsRequired` property in the template? - `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsRequired)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Yes.

Comment: Not sure what else may be causing the validation to not be triggered ([`RequiredIfTrue]` works fine for me)

Comment: @StephenMuecke - That's what had me scratching my head for a while now. Does it work for you in the `EditorTemplate` and you send a `List<T>` to it from a parent view?

Comment: Yes (have used this in a previous project). But give me a few minutes and I reproduce your code to be sure.

Comment: Have tested `[RequiredIfTrue]` using `EditorTemplate` with a collection and your right, did not work (only for single item). I will need to check my other project tomorrow to see what we did to get this working and will let you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc)

> Note that FluentValidation will also work with ASP.NET MVC's client-side validation, but not all rules are supported. For example, any rules defined using a condition (with When/Unless), custom validators, or calls to Must will not run on the client side

Because you have used a `.When` condition, you will not get client side validation.

Using an alternative such as [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIfTrue]` attribute will work for a simple property, but not for a complex object or collection.

You can solve this by creating you own custom `ValidationAttribute` that implements `IClientValidatable`

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class ComplexRequiredIfTrue : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private const string _DefaultErrorMessage = "The {0} field is required.";
    public string OtherProperty { get; private set; }
    public ComplexRequiredIfTrue(string otherProperty) : base(_DefaultErrorMessage)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(otherProperty))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("otherProperty");
        }
        OtherProperty = otherProperty;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(ErrorMessageString, name, OtherProperty);
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            PropertyInfo otherProperty = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(OtherProperty);
            bool isRequired = (bool)otherProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
            if (isRequired)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var clientValidationRule = new ModelClientValidationRule()
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
            ValidationType = "complexrequirediftrue"
        };
        clientValidationRule.ValidationParameters.Add("otherproperty", OtherProperty);
        return new[] { clientValidationRule };
    }
}
```

and the associated script

```
function nameToIndex (value) {
  return value.replace(/[\[\].]/g, '_');
}

(function ($) {
  $.validator.addMethod("complexrequirediftrue", function (value, element, params) {
    // We need to get the prefix of the control we are validating
    // so we can get the corresponding 'other property'
    var name = $(element).attr('name');
    var index = name.lastIndexOf('.');
    var prefix = nameToIndex(name.substr(0, index + 1));
    var otherProp = $('#' + prefix + params);
    if (otherProp.val() == "True" && !value) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
  $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("complexrequirediftrue", "otherproperty");
}(jQuery));
```

then apply it to you property

```
public class ChildModel
{
  public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
  [ComplexRequiredIfTrue("IsRequired")]
  public string foo { get; set; }
}
```

and in the `EditorTemplate`, include `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsRequired)`

```
@model ChildModel
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsRequired)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.foo)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.foo)
```

Edit: Further to comments, if the controller is

```
model.ChildModels = new List<ChildModel>() { new ChildModel() { IsRequired = true }, new ChildModel() };
return View(model);
```

then the html generated when the submit button is clicked is:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsRequired field is required." id="ChildModels_0__IsRequired" name="ChildModels[0].IsRequired" type="hidden" value="True">
<input class="input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-complexrequirediftrue="The foo field is required." data-val-complexrequirediftrue-otherproperty="IsRequired" id="ChildModels_0__foo" name="ChildModels[0].foo" type="text" value="">
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="ChildModels[0].foo" data-valmsg-replace="true">The foo field is required.</span>
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsRequired field is required." id="ChildModels_1__IsRequired" name="ChildModels[1].IsRequired" type="hidden" value="False">
<input data-val="true" data-val-complexrequirediftrue="The foo field is required." data-val-complexrequirediftrue-otherproperty="IsRequired" id="ChildModels_1__foo" name="ChildModels[1].foo" type="text" value="">
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ChildModels[1].foo" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Note the form did not submit and the error message was displayed for the first textbox

Comment: Thanks for this. I have added all of this, and it still isn't triggered. I've watched in firebug as I click 'submit'...I can see the class of my input change to append `valid` and add the `aria-describedby` item as well. The validation message `<span>` does not flip to visible.  This is my input tag - `<input type="text" name="ChildModels[0].foo" id="ChildModels_0__foo" data-val-complexrequirediftrue-otherproperty="IsRequired" data-val-complexrequirediftrue="The foo field is required." data-val="true" class="text-box single-line valid" value="" aria-describedby="ChildModels_0__foo-error">`

Comment: Not sure what `aria-describedby` is. Give me a few minutes and I will update answer with the actual html generated by my testing of this (which gives me client side validation)

Comment: See update with generated html. Its working for me so so sure what other issues there may be. Perhaps put a breakpoint on the script and step through it.

Comment: There must be something slightly different about my situation than the one you recreated, but this got me 99% there. I added a little hack in the javascript to replace `[`, `]` and `.` with `_` and it finally found the right selector, which then found the proper `.val()`. I thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I have a function `nameToIndex(value)` in a separate utility file which does just that. I deleted it thinking it was not relevant but of course it is! Have updated the answer :)